# Make Webview App with Tabs

Tags: android, webview

how can I can make Webview App with tabs? I made a Webview App, but no tabs. I want Webview with tabs. For example, first tab is Facebook, second tab is Twitter, third tab is Instagram etc. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

are you familiar with [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html)? or [Google with multiple examles?](https://www.google.pl/search?q=android%20tabs) just set inside proper on click/pick/select listener (for `TabLayout` it will be [OnTabSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener.html)) `webView. loadUrl(url);` method